# Create dynamic argument list from _call() functions $arg array

Tags: php, oop

I am upgrading a php library to its latest version (a bit of a rewrite) & a problem I have is that the author decided to camelcase all of his functions. He's done it consistently, so I thought to try this trick in an inherited class:

```
<?php
// this will extend animal..just demo code
class dog {

public function __call($method, $args) {
    // I have a function to camelcase this - only for developing
    $call_method = 'barkLoud';

    //this is so it doesn't blow up - this is what I'm trying to fix
    $myArgsList = 120;  
    $this->$call_method($myArgsList);
}   

function barkLoud($decibals)
{
    echo 'Barking at '. $decibals;
}
}

$poppy = new dog;
print $poppy->bar_loud(100);
```

What I don't understand how to do is: There will be a variable number of arguments, of variable type (ints, strings, arrays, objects, ...)

How can I break up $args in such a way that it correctly builds the parameter list that would go where $myArgList placeholder is now?

(Remember, my args may be arrays or objects, so please no suggestions to build out strings with implode() ... Also please remember that I do not want to change the new Library class at all)

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `return call_user_func_array(array($this,$call_method), $args);`

Comment: I knew the answer was one of those call_ functions, but couldn't sort out what I needed. Thanks! (I'll accept in a minute)